# Check when object collides with border of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm fairly new to Canvas HTML5 and was curious to know how to check if the 'Hero' in my game has collided with the border of the canvas as I would like to give it an alert or something if it did.

Here is my current code:

```
// Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Background image
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function () {
    bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "images/background.png";

// Hero image
var heroReady = false;
var heroImage = new Image();
heroImage.onload = function () {
    heroReady = true;
};
heroImage.src = "images/hero.png";

// Monster image
var monsterReady = false;
var monsterImage = new Image();
monsterImage.onload = function () {
    monsterReady = true;
};
monsterImage.src = "images/flamingo.png";

// Game objects
var hero = {
    speed: 256 // movement in pixels per second
};
var monster = {};
var monstersCaught = 0;

// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};

addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);

// Reset the game when the player catches a monster
var reset = function () {
    hero.x = canvas.width / 2;
    hero.y = canvas.height / 2;

    // Throw the monster somewhere on the screen randomly
    monster.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
    monster.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));
};

// Update game objects
var update = function (modifier) {
    if (38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
        hero.y -= hero.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
        hero.y += hero.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
        hero.x -= hero.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (39 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
        hero.x += hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    // Are they touching?
    if (
        hero.x <= (monster.x + 32)
        && monster.x <= (hero.x + 32)
        && hero.y <= (monster.y + 32)
        && monster.y <= (hero.y + 32)
    ) 
    {
        ++monstersCaught;
        reset();
    }


};

// Draw everything
var render = function () {
    if (bgReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    }

    if (heroReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y);
    }

    if (monsterReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, monster.x, monster.y);
    }

    // Score
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 250)";
    ctx.font = "24px Helvetica";
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    ctx.fillText("Flamingos slaughtered: " + monstersCaught, 32, 32);

};

// The main game loop
var main = function () {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;

    update(delta / 1000);
    render();

    then = now;
};

// Let's play this game!
reset();
var then = Date.now();
setInterval(main, 1); // Execute as fast as possible
```

Comment: the collision with the monster is a more complex task that the collision with the screen border... What difficulties did you run into ?

Comment: Just referring to the screen border, would I refer to the length or?

Comment: 0 <= x < canvas.width  and  0 <= y < canvas.height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what GameAlchemist has told ,should work.

But if the screen is resized or something similar.

You should go for

```
0 <= x < window.innerWidth
```

and

```
0 <= x < window.innerHeight
```

Condition: Windows size and canvas size should be equal

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong. canvas and window size are different things (except, of course, if you set them equal).  
@OliverK : if you want to have full window canvas, do not forget to set document.body.style.padding = '0px' to avoid scrollers to show.

Comment: Oh yes,canvas and window size should be equal.
I was making a game myselves and was speaking in that context. :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this :

```
var update = function (modifier) {
    if (38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
        hero.y -= hero.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
        hero.y += hero.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
        hero.x -= hero.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (39 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
        hero.x += hero.speed * modifier;
    }

    // Are they touching?
    if (
        hero.x <= (monster.x + 32)
        && monster.x <= (hero.x + 32)
        && hero.y <= (monster.y + 32)
        && monster.y <= (hero.y + 32)
    ) {
        ++monstersCaught;
        reset();
    }
    if(hero.x <= 0){
        hero.x = 0;
    }
    else if(isMaxWidth()){
        hero.x = canvas.width -32
    }
    if(hero.y <= 0){
        hero.y = 0;
    }
    else if(isMaxHeight()){
        hero.y = canvas.height -32
    }

};

var isMaxWidth = function(){
    return hero.x >= canvas.width - 32;
};

var isMaxHeight = function(){
    return hero.y >= canvas.height - 32;
};
```

Regards.